# Can we change targetSdkVersion of an APK using Apktool

Tags: android, apktool

I have an app on Google play store and I want to update it but I don't have the source code, when I tried to update it Google didn't accept the updated APK because it's targetSdkVersion is 27, I need to update it to 28, is there any solution for that using a reverse engineering tool like apktool ???

Help me please

Answer (score 3):

apktool d $APK_PATH -o $OUTPUT_FOLDER

- Open the apktool.yml text file
- Alter the versionCode and versionName entries
- now rebuild!
- apktool build $OUTPUT_FOLDER
- next you need to re-sign the apk with the original keystore file
  jarsigner -verbose -keystore $KEYSTORE_PATH -storepass $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD -keypass $KEYSTORE_KEY_PASSWORD $APK_PATH $KEYSTORE_KEY_NAME
  ~/android-sdk/build-tools/21.1.1/zipalign  -v 4 $APK_PATH $APK_OUT_PATH